# I can't deploy this app on Heruko but I can run it locally

Tags: node.js, heroku, oauth-2.0

NodeJS app runs locally but I can't get it to deploy on Heroku.
The app I'm trying to deploy is [here](https://github.com/mcohen01/node-quickbooks). (It's an app that does Oauth2 but Oauth2 is not my issue).
When installing the app and getting it to run locally I do '$npm install' in the root directory, cd into oauth2example type '$npm install' again, and '$node app.js', which launches the app locally on port 3000.

Before deploying to Heroku I put this (below) in the root package.json to replicate what I did to get the app running locally. I suspect my problem is here.
(You'll notice below for start it has just "node ". When I had "node app.js" the log said 'app/app.js could not be found'.)

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ",
    "test": "mocha",
    "client": "npm start --prefix oauth2example",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm install && npm install --prefix oauth2example"
},
```

In 'oauth2example/app.js' on lines 53 and 74 I change the urls from...

```
http://localhost:' + port + '/...'
```

to

```
'https://<app_name>.herokuapp.com/...'
```

I also change the link the same way in the oauth2example/views/intuit.ejs file and have tried deploying with every variation keeping all links the same or unchanged.

You'll notice on line 4 of oauth2example/app.js the port is

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
```

I believe 'process.env.PORT' is what is required for Heroku. I don't know what other factor needs to be set when deploying on Heroku vs deploying locally.

I do the typical deploy to Heroku steps

```
$git init
$ heroku git:remote -a slamham
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "make it better"
$ git push heroku master
```

Logs are not very descriptive of the problem

```
2019-12-25T14:42:59.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-12-25T14:43:01.802807+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-12-25T14:43:04.649949+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-12-25T14:43:04.634670+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2019-12-25T14:43:04.452419+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-12-25T14:43:04.452440+00:00 app[web.1]: > node-quickbooks@2.0.33 start /app
2019-12-25T14:43:04.452442+00:00 app[web.1]: > node
2019-12-25T14:43:04.452444+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-12-25T14:43:08.767084+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=pingpong11.herokuapp.com request_id=f923d9de-b7c4-4cb4-a932-d22c42ef660e fwd="65.60.197.111" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

and the link that should load the app always says 'Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.'

Again, the entire repo for the app I'm trying to deploy is [here](https://github.com/mcohen01/node-quickbooks).

Comment: What do you mean by "deploy locally"? Does `yarn start` / `npm run start` work locally? I'd be very surprised, as your `"start"` script just runs `node` without any arguments. I don't know how your code is set up, but you probably need to provide the name of your main script as an argument there.

Comment: (We're not going to go off-site to dig through your code. Please include the relevant parts _here_, as code blocks directly in your question. We don't need everything, but we do need a [mcve].)

Comment: "Does yarn start / npm run start work locally?" 'Node app.js' in the oauth2example folder starts the app locally. Sorry I wrote 'deploy locally' poor choice of words. I changed it. @Chris I was hesitant to ask, but don't know how to replicate deploying whole app here. I put up every single thing I changed and did to get it to deploy, unless there is something specific I can add that I missed.

Comment: `node app.js` isn't the same as running your `start` script. See Pat's answer.

Answer (score 1):

2nd line of the Heroku output logs is

> 2019-12-25T14:43:01.802807+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`

The package.json has the start script as only `node`, when it should be something like `node oauth2example/app.js`

Also, you might need to [include the `engines`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#specify-the-version-of-node) field inside package.json . For example,

```
"engines": {
    "node": "10.x"
  },
```

Comment: Additionally, that same page linked to above has a section titled [Build your app and run it locally](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#build-your-app-and-run-it-locally) describing the command `heroku local web`, which is probably a good test to catch any deployment-related errors before actually deploying

Comment: Thank you. Added "engines" and under "scripts" put  "start": "node oauth2example/app.js" and it launches on port 5000 with $heroku local web but it can't find the other files in the oauth2example. "Error: Failed to lookup view "intuit.ejs" in views directory "views"" It's looking for them in the folder above that one. Sorry, my understanding of 'scripts' in package.jsons isn't what it should be

Comment: I see it should work in that directory if I ran "npm start --prefix path/to/your/app" but 'start' is the script. So I need a script below the start script to run "npm start ..." that will execute upon being deployed.

Comment: I got it working by moving the operative files in oauth2example into the root folder and copying dependencies in oauth2example.package.json into the roots folder's package.json and made sure everything was pointing in the right direction in the moved files. Under 'scripts' all I need now is "  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  }"

Comment: Nice! What are the operative files?

Comment: Just 'app.js' and the views folder in oauth2example. It works but the whole deploy thing is still a little murky. No build needed here apparently. Not sure when build and npm install and making that happen in different folders has to happen.